# Is there a way to get all nodes in go client filtered by NodeSelectorTerms?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have a nodeSelectorTerms that I pass to pod spec to set nodeAffinity.
In the other part of my project, I like to list all nodes that match those terms. Is there any solution to this?

I want some thing like this:

```
    nodeList := &corev1.NodeList{}
    if err := r.Client.List(context.Background(), nodeList, &client.Selector{config.NodeSelectorTerms}); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return nodeList, nil
```